# Is this exercise (8.24) from Torchinsky's book on analysis right?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is the exercise (the book does not provide an answer for this one):

8.24: Let $X$ be a normed linear space and for $K\subset X$ and $x\in X$, let
$D_K(x)=\{y\in X:||y-x||=d(x,K)\}$. Prove that if $K$ is convex, $D_K(x)$ is
convex for all $x\in X$.

I think that $D_K(x)$ is not convex, because it is a sphere of center $x$ and radius $d(x,K)$. Could it be a typo in the definition of $D_K(x)$?

This exercise appears at page 110 of[image] the book https://www.amazon.es/Problems-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1470420570

Comment: Depends on what $d(x,K)$ is ! I think $d(x,y)$ is Distance between Point $x$ & Point $y$. What about Set $K$ ? Does the Author Define that Case ? There are Certain Definitions where the Conclusion will be true. There are Certain Definitions where the Conclusion will not be true.

Comment: I would guess that $D_K(x)=\{y \in K \ldots$ was meant, which would make more sense to me.

Comment: I think not. $D_K(x)$ might have Points outside $K$ , @Ingix , It might be the Set of Points Equi-Distant from the "Whole Set" $K$. In that Case , it might be Convex. Depends on what $d(x,K)$ is !

Comment: @Prem $d(x, K)=\inf \{d(x,y):y\in K\}$

Comment: I agree with @Prem about the standard meaning of distance from a point to a set. My guess about the exercise is that $\Vert y-x\Vert=d(x,K)$ should have been $\Vert y-x\Vert=d(y,K)$.

Comment: Probably you should give the book's title and the page number(s). His [**Real-Variable Methods in Harmonic Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0126954607) doesn't have any exercises, and I can't find an exercise labeled 8.24 in his [**Real Variables**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/020115675X).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro this is the book https://www.amazon.es/Problems-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1470420570

Comment: Interesting ... I did not know he had written another "introductory" book besides his 1988 **Real Variables** book. FYI, I took a 2-semester real analysis course under him during the 1982-1983 academic year that covered the material in his 1988 book, which I probably purchased around 1989.